# Parse a JSON string to an array using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I get the following JSON response:

```
[
{
    "name": "Assets",
    "id": "assets---0020",
    "elements": [
        {
            "name": "user generates an token",
            "steps": [
            {
                "name": "I have generated a common access token",
                "result": {
                    "duration": 1124800,
                    "status": "passed"
                }                    
            }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "user generates an token",
            "steps": [
            { 
                "name": "I have generated a common access token",
                "result": {
                    "duration": 1124800,
                    "status": "passed"
                }                    
            }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "User clicks on dropdown",
            "steps": [
            {
                "name": "User clicks on dropdown and selects option and api response printed",
                "result": {
                    "duration": 1124800,
                    "status": "failed"
                }
            }
            ]
        }
    ]    
}
]
```

I want below output:

```
Name: Assets
Total - 3
No Of Success - 2
No Of Failed - 1
```

I've been trying to parse it automatically with Jackson with little/no success. I am able to display:

```
Name: Assets
```

below is code for my main Java class:

```
package JsonToJava.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


public class JsontoJava
{

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException
    {        
       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

       try {            
      
          Data[] dataObj  = mapper.readValue(new File("data/sample_array_data.json"), Data[].class);
       
      
          for (Data data: dataObj) {
           
             System.out.println("Track Name--->"+data.getName());
            
             System.out.println("Printing Elements--->"+data.getElements());
            
             System.out.println("------------------------");
          }
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } 
   }
}
```

But not getting how to loop elements & get desired data from it.
Anyone know what is the solution? Please help.

Comment: If you parse the json to `Data` then just iterate over the resulting object like you would do with any other Pojo. If you're struggingling with that you might want to revisit Java basics and especially topics about loops, arrays, collections and maps. If `Data` itself is the problem then you should show that class since otherwise all we can do is guess.

Comment: @Thomas - added class file code in previous edit.

Comment: You still didn't share the `Data` class but the code you posted has a `data.getElements()`. Assuming that returns a list or array of `Element` (or similar), what's the problem with adding another loop to iterate over the elements and maybe another for the steps and collecting status counts into  a `Map<String, Integer>` or so? To update the value in the map, have a look at `Map.compute()`.

Answer (score 0):

Click this link [jsonschema2pojo](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)
and paste your JSON code. Type the name of your file and package and select both the radio buttons **JSON** and **jackson 2.x**. Click ***preview*** and copy the code displayed in the modal window.

Screenshot

[image: jsonschema2pok]

Answer (score 0):

So you have a list of JSON objects ( in the question this list contains only one element) and you have defined `Data` class that can map this single json object, right?

In this case this question is actually about how to parse a list of object with jackson:

Here is an answer:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

...
String str = "...";
List<Data> dataList = objectMapper.readValue(str, new TypeReference<List<Data>>(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this `Data[] datas  = mapper.readValue(new File("sample_json_file.json"), Data[].class);` then loop through.